# In C, how can I pass an array to a function?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
int length(int *array[]){
    int len = sizeof(*array) / sizeof(*array[0]);
    printf("The array is of length %d\n",len);
    return len;
}



int main(){
    int array[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int len = length(&array);
    ...
}
```

The code above is meant to return the length of an array.However, I get an error when I try to call length from main():

```
cannot convert int(*)[10] to int** for argument 1 to int length(int**)
```

How do I pass array to length correctly?

Comment: An array is not a pointer. A pointer is not an array. An array decays into a pointer to its first element when passed to a function. Hence, it is impossible to write a function which returns the length of an array. `int *array[]` is not a pointer-to-array, it would be an array of pointers in other contexts, but inside a function declaration, it's a pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: When you pass an array to a function, it decays to a pointer to the start of the array. So `sizeof` is not going to tell you the correct length.

Comment: BTW, if you google ["sizeof array incorrect"](https://www.google.hu/search?q=sizeof+array+incorrect), then the **very first four results** are links to identical questions of which this one is a duplicate. Is it really that hard to use Google?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I did not realized the problem lies in using sizeof, otherwise I would have search for that. In any case, I appreciate your original constructive response and I understand my mistake now.

Comment: In C you cannot pass an array to a function. You can pass a pointer to its first element and the length (this is usual); you can wrap the array inside a structure and pass that structure, ...

Answer (score 0):

Define the function the following way

```
int length( int ( *array )[10])
{
    int len = sizeof(*array) / sizeof( ( *array )[0]);
    printf("The array is of length %d\n",len);
    return len;
}
```

In general case if you want to pass an array to a function then you should also pass its size yourself because arrays are converted to pointers to their first elements when they used in expressions including arguments.

So for example these three function declarations are equivalent and declare the same function

```
void f( int array[10] );
void f( int array[] );
void f( int *array );
```

Comment: And would this be any useful? No, because you can only ever pass it an array of 10 elements.

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant it is not your problem. I showed how the function shall be defined correctly if the argument is expression &array. So it is very useful for the author of the topic.

Comment: Hardly. "The code above is meant to return the length of an array" - it's not meant to return the length of arrays of size 10. It's meant to return the length of an array of *any* elements. (which, as I mentioned, is not possible.)

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant Read the title of his topic.

Comment: read the question itself. OP's post, just like many other questions, has a misleading/irrelevant title. The *real* question is obviously not "how to pass an array to a function", but rather "how to write a function that returns the count of an array".

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant You may present your own answer. What is the problem?!

Answer (score 0):

- When you do `sizeof(array)` in `main()` you will get the size of array which is `number of elements * size of int`.
- When you do `sizeof(*array)` in `length()` you will get the size of pointer which is `size of int`.

So when you send the `array` to `length()`, you are actually sending the base address of `array`. And when we pass address of a variable to a function, it will store the address in a pointer. 
So again if you try to get the size of `array` you'll get the size of pointer.

> How do I pass array to length correctly?

If you want to calculate the length of `array` you can do that in `main()`.

`len = sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);`

Comment: This is a good answer. Why was it downvoted?

Comment: Even I was surprised to see a down-vote...

Comment: The only possibility that makes sense is, "It doesn't answer the OP's question of how to write a `length` function to do this," to which I would reply, "Except in the case of an array terminated with a sentinel value, which isn't necessarily the case and also makes the calculation slower since the entire array must be searched for the sentinel value, you must pass the length to any function since arrays decay to pointers, defeating the function's purpose. A function-like macro could be used, as in `#define length(array) (sizeof array / sizeof *array)`, but not a function."

Comment: The size of a pointer may not equal the size of an int.